# Discord.js Bot status to "Watching Over (amount of humans)"

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my status:

```js
bot.on("ready", async() => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online on ${bot.guilds.size} servers!`);
    bot.user.setActivity(`Azrael is ruling the world!`)
})
```

**I want to change it to watching over the total amount of members in every server the bot is in, how do I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using `bot.users.cache.size`

```js
bot.user.setActivity(`Watching Over ${bot.users.cache.size}`)
```

Comment: Thank you but i tired that but it says "Watching Over undefined" (https://imgur.com/pvEtu9x)

Comment: what version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I am using discord v12

Comment: I have updated my answer, I thought you were using v11 because of your code above

Comment: ohh is there a way for discord v12?